# Get InnerHTML from many elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

My problem is simple and I still couldn't get it done. I don't know exactly what is wrong with my code and it makes me quite unhappy.

All i wanted to do is to get the `InnerHTML` texts into the div element with the `hna` ID.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='button' value='test' onclick='tst()'>
  <div class='paragraphe'>
    <div class='bloc_agence'>
      <h3>wa7d</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='paragraphe'>
  <div class='bloc_agence'>
    <h3>joj</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='paragraphe'>
  <div class='bloc_agence'>
    <h3>tlata</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='hna'></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
a=document.getElementsByClassName('paragraphe').children.getElementsByClassName('bloc_agence').children.getElementsByTagName('H3');

function tst(){
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
document.getElementById('hna').InnerHTML+=a[i].InnerHTML+'<br>';
    }}
```

My live [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt3yL/)

Comment: Do we really have **.children** method?

Comment: @KunJ a property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children

Comment: I remember the days when it was OK to answer a pure JavaScript question with a pure JavaScript answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with JQuery

```
    function tst(){
$('#hna').empty();
$('.bloc_agence h3').each(function(){
   var tex=$(this).text() 
   $('#hna').append(tex+'</br>');
});
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt3yL/4/)

Comment: Maybe there is a reason, why the post was not tagged with [jQuery]. If I'd added a [LISP] tag and gave an answer with LISP, would it be correct?

Comment: Teemu you're smart .. i didn't tag jquery  
but thanks ..  
i want insert this code on an existing webpage (in the URL barre)  
so i changed this giving code to this `javascript:a=document.querySelectorAll('.bloc_agence > h3');alert(for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){a[i].innerHTML+'<br>';})`
but it didn't work .. i want to copy all those elements to the clipboard (i needed to insert a database into excel)

Comment: @Sridhar R: Absolutely right but not in JS :) though it is useful, I am removing negativity from you answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to improve some syntax and use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
a = document.querySelectorAll('.bloc_agence > h3');

function tst() {
    var str = '';        
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        str  += a[i].innerHTML + '<br>'; // Not InnerHTML it must be innerHTML
    }
 document.getElementById('hna').innerHTML = str;
}
```

[**<kbd>Updated Fiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt3yL/7/)

Comment: A small side note: it is better to build a string for `innerHTML` and assign it once.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the wrong level of elements prior to your `for()` loop. You want to only get an array of the outer-most elements and then loop through them (`.paragraphe`):

```
function tst(){
    a = document.getElementsByClassName('paragraphe');

    str = '';
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       header = a[i].getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];
       str += header.innerHTML+'<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById('hna').innerHTML = str;  
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/6LCwg/1/)

Comment: I appreciate your answer oGeez.